# Does the Daydream remote work with Processing?

Tags: processing, daydream

Was wondering if it's possible for the Daydream remote to work with the Processing IDE google VR applications. recently I've been working on a project that allows the Daydream remote co ordinates to be sent over to the VR app. Is there any way for me to code the Daydream remote in Processing or is that functionality not provided?